# SQL counting the number of ones in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table and as you can see the ids are not the same. So I can't do group by. I need to count all the ones that are in sequence. Like from id 9 to 13, from id 20 to 23. How i do it?

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: sql-server 2012

Comment: You havent specified your expected output.

Comment: Can you mention your expected output. Solution you accepted doesn't seems to give correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with `LAG` and `LEAD`.

```
;WITH StackValues AS
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        PreviousStatus = LAG(T.Status, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY T.ID ASC),
        NextStatus = LEAD(T.Status, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY T.ID ASC)
    FROM
        #YourTable AS T
),
ValuesToSum AS
(
    SELECT
        L.*,
        ValueToSum = CASE 
            WHEN L.Status = 1 AND L.PreviousStatus = 1 AND L.NextStatus = 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END
    FROM
        StackValues AS L
)
SELECT
    Total = SUM(V.ValueToSum)
FROM
    ValuesToSum AS V
```

`LAG` will give you the `N` previous row (`N = 1` for this example) while `LEAD` will give you the `N` next row (`N = 1` for this example). The query generates another column (`ValueToSum`) based on the previous and next values and uses it's result to sum.

Comment: code is not giving expected output, just giving single number.

Comment: Ok, this is counting all the ones on the table. But I need to sum it up like between id 9 to 13 I will count it as one. I need to sum up all the sequences.